# KQL split row into several row with numeric resolution

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

I want to split a row like

| Row | Event | StartIndex | EndIndex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | B | 1.9 | 2.7 |

That in the new table, the Event will be written several times with specific index based on StartIndex and EndIndex, with a resolution of 0.5. For example, the expected output is:

| Row | Event | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 2 | A | 0.5 |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 4 | A | 1.5 |
| 5 | A | 2 |
| 6 | A | 2.5 |
| 7 | A | 3 |
| 8 | B | 2 |
| 9 | B | 2.5 |

How can I do that in KQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should get you started - using `range()` and `mv-expand`.
if required, you can extend the solution and 'override' `Row` using the `row_number()` function.

```
datatable(Row:long, Event:string, StartIndex:long, EndIndex:long)
[
    1, 'A', 0,  3,
    2, 'B', 1.9,    2.7,
]
| mv-expand Index = range(StartIndex, EndIndex, 0.5)
| project Row, Event, Index
```

| Row | Event | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 0 |
| 1 | A | 0.5 |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | 1.5 |
| 1 | A | 2 |
| 1 | A | 2.5 |
| 1 | A | 3 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 2 | B | 2.5 |
| 2 | B | 3 |